# Customisable iOS Interface

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, user-interface, customization

I am currently developing an iOS app that can be used by different clients keeping pretty much the same interface for all of them. I would like to make this interface somehow “customisable” without having to change the storyboard for every client but I am not sure how to do so.

I thought that maybe I could have some sort of XML file that would contain the value of the UI elements, modify it and have the app read the value of the UI elements from it at compile time so the final app would contain the desired messages, images, etc.

To make the changes easier I also thought of some kind of “wizard” that would show the UI elements that can be changed, allow me to edit and write them to the xml file and after all that, compile the app from the command line (running a script from inside the wizard).

Is my idea viable? If so, how can I accomplish it or what tool are out there that might help me?

Is there another option that would help me accomplish this “customisable” interface?

Note: this is my first iOS app and is still being developed, I searched for related topics and info but found nothing useful so I am not sure if I am asking even possible to do for iOS or if it is out there under another "name".

**Edit**: by customisable I mean being able to change the text of the messages, the labels, the banner, the clients img logo, color of some elements and that kind of things.

**Edit 2** what I would like is to develop a "wizard" that will modify an xml file and maybe replace some images in my app before it is compiled (that is my current idea). After that I would compile it and all the customisation would be done and the app would be ready for the client.

Comment: customisable in the sense ?

Comment: what else you gonna change in the storyboard ? do you mean changing colors and font etc....is it what you mean customizable?

Comment: I mean to change the text of the messages, the labels, the banner, the clients logo, color and that kind of things.

Comment: if that is the case....you have to do it all the way as per my knowledge. It is difficult to maintain single file which could store all the references to many other things....

Comment: I was thinking of something like the Strings.xml file that android has, something that I can change, and stays with the app. Maybe implementing my own "Strings.xml" file in form of a plist and modify it in this wizard and then just compile the app. What do you think?

Comment: you are not going to keep all those resources in your app right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Lets say my UILabel's text is "Hello" and that value I read it from an xml file. If I edit that xml I would end up changing the text without adding anything else, the same goes for the images and colours, they are already there, I would just change their value.

Comment: it is ok for texts....what will you do for images? Do you store them somewhere else and store the path in xml?

Comment: even the plist works well for only the local version. You can't modify the plist once the app is out.

Comment: What if you ship your app with a default xml file and "download" a modified version once app is run (given that there is internet connectivity). Of course, downloaded version has precedence over default one.

Comment: I would use `Core Dat`a to store `strings` and maybe some `BOOLS` if its the case to save the settings and preferences of the user, and then make some `switch` cases to apply the config. Modify and work with an XML sounds more complicated for me.

Comment: I believe we are not on the same page, what I would like is to develop a "wizard" that will modify an xml file and maybe replace some images in my app before it is compile. After that I would compile it and all the customisation would be done, the app would be ready for the client and there wouldn't be any more interface changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at targets http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code

You could generate your XML file for each "Target", but only include the correct one for each target. Then when the app is compiled it should include all the relevant information. If you are producing multiple apps, you also need to consider that the app bundle Id would need to be different for each. Again Targets handles this

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and get back to you

Comment: I looked into it and think it would be just what I need, it lets me handle the images issue and including just the right XML file would complement it. Just a couple questions: 1) do you think that this could this be done form the command line so my "wizard" creates the target, edits it and compile it? or would I need to use the "wizard" just for the edition of the files and creation of the assets and then do the other part manually?

Comment: I've never tried from the command line, so sorry I can't help with that